Usernamespace support in GKE 1.30
I am no GKE 1.30, trying to create a pod with usernamspace using hostUsers:false, but GKE is ignoring it and creating the POD with actual host root user.
Is usernamspace support is enabled with GKE 1.30?
I tried with both the node images COS and Ubuntu. With below POD defination.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ns-test
spec:
  hostUsers: true
  containers:
  - name: sleep
    command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
    image: ubuntu

After creating the POD I have cheked inside the container using command
cat /proc/self/uidmap and it showing mapping as 0 0 4294967295
